# need help for exam please (deadline tomorrow)

Tags: buzzer

what we're required to do on exam [image]

You don't have to completely give me the answers, I just started learning this yesterday so I'm pressured on learning it properly + the exam, thx

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us at least what you have available. (Sensors, Boards, etc.).

Comment: That doesn't mention what sensor you are using for the intruder alarm. I'm sure there are several tutorials and opensource projects about this on the web. Have you searched for them?

Comment: I just asked someone and they said we didn't have to use sensors, just make sure 3 LED lights and the buzzer works together.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Where do you get the distance from if you don't use sensors?

Comment: I'm not sure as well, the tool for that isn't discussed at all in our handouts except now which didn't specify what we should use. I think it's the ultrasonic distance sensor since that's what I saw on my kit

Comment: I'm guessing the question is just asking you to create a conditional loop that will have the Arduino illuminate the appropriate LED when each stipulated condition is met.

Comment: You should easily find tutorials for your sensor. The ultrasonic sensor typically used in many kits is the HC-SR04. Just google for something like "HC-SR04 tutorial"

Comment: Please include the rest of the question in the question, instead of a link to a picture of the text of the question. Being specific about the actual problem(s) faced is helpful. I might consider a tutorial, or writing this exam off and starting sooner for the next one.

Answer (score 4):

As written, the exam does not look like you are expected to build
something functional. Rather, that you must show that you understand how
to drive LEDs and a buzzer, how to write conditional code, etc. I would
suggest using a pot to simulate a distance reading, and writing
something along these lines:

```cpp
void loop() {
    // Simulate a distance reading between 0 and 4 meters.
    float distance = analogRead(A0) * (4.0/1023);

    // React to the sensor reading.
    if (distance < 3) {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
}
```